# Can others see questions deleted by OP and possibly undelete them?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

1. Can users with enough reputation see questions deleted by the OP?
2. Can they vote to undelete them?

Edit: I erroneously used *closed* instead of *deleted*.

**BTW: this confusion is caused by the dialog 'vote to delete that post'**

Comment: I know you can cast close votes on your own questions, but as far as I know, it won't happen unless 4 other people agree with you.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't thinking of *deleted* questions? A question asker can't close their own question - they can only vote to close if they have the rep to do so.

Comment: @Michael Petrotta Yes I was thinking of deleted questions.

Comment: Have I to edit the question to 'can others see questions deleted by OP and possibly reopen them' or have I to ask a new question?

Comment: 10K users can see deleted questions. The 10K tools show recently deleted questions. Deleted questions have an undelete link. If it was deleted by a moderator clicking this link gives a message that it can't be undeleted. If deleted by the OP it needs three undelete votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can users with enough reputation see questions deleted by the OP?

Yes. You need 10k rep to see deleted questions and deleted answers from other users.

Anyone can see their own deleted answers (regardless of who deleted it).

> Can they vote to <s>reopen</s> undelete them?

Yes. You can *vote* to undelete your own deleted answers and questions<sup>1</sup>.

If you deleted it yourself, you can undelete immediately.

If it was deleted by other people, your vote will count as a single undelete vote. You'll need more people to agree with you.

If it was deleted by a moderator, only a moderator can undelete it.

---

<sup>1</sup> To cast an undelete vote, you need to be able to see the post. This means if you are under 10k, you will have some difficulty casting an undelete vote to your own *questions* (but it's [not impossible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109412/users-under-10k-can-cast-undelete-votes-to-their-questions)).

See also: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean)