# Users under 10k can cast undelete votes to their questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deleted-questions, undelete

I know this is very minor, but a user who has less than 10k reputation can cast an undelete vote to their own questions, provided they know how to do it:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7779581/revisions (you need 10k on SO)

This just means no check is done on the server side as to whether they can cast the vote or not.

Comment: Why shouldn't they be able to have a say in it? If nobody agrees with them, no harm done, question stays deleted.

Comment: In that case, I think what happened was the user hit the delete button thinking it would automatically vanish and he'd be taken away.  He could still "see" the question since he didn't navigate away from the page so he clicked again (and again and again).

Comment: @lunboks IDK, you can't see your own deleted questions if you don't have 10k rep. So you shouldn't be able to undelete them.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionஇ_இ Oh, didn't know that. I just sort of assumed you could, since you can see your own deleted answers.

Answer (score 1):

Jeff Mercado is correct in saying:

> He could still "see" the question since he didn't navigate away from the page so he clicked again (and again and again).

When you delete a post, it doesn't immediately become inaccessible to <10k users. They see the same screen, but with a faint red background. If they try to refresh the page or come back to it later, it disappears, but not instantly.

From the revision history, it looks like that's exactly what happened. Intuitively, when you delete something, it should disappear. However, the user being new here, was not aware that nothing is ever really deleted and was confused that he can still see his contents and so kept clicking again and again. By the way, [this feature of allowing users to see the deleted question until they refresh](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean) is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

You always have the ability to delete your questions and answers (and by extension, undelete it). It's true that you're not allowed to see the deleted question when the page is refreshed, but you're allowed to see your own deleted answers if you know the link to the question. So the ability to undelete is useful when you delete an answer and then improve it and undelete. It's probably easier to code and maintain undelete rights across both questions and answers the same way. The system only makes a check to see if the post can be deleted (i.e., is not accepted or has no upvoted answers)

Comment: That was me, using a test account. I don't think it matters whether I refresh it or not. In all likelihood, I can cast the undelete vote as long as I am able to reproduce the AJAX request.

Comment: and what is wrong with casting an undelete vote? That's also status-bydesign. Users are prevented from undeleting themselves only when it is deleted by others or by a moderator.

Comment: Well, why can't they see the question itself then?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionஇ_இ: Oh... that was you?  NUE... heh.  Try deleting then open that same question again from a new tab.  You lose the ability to undelete the moment you cannot see the page (cached or not).

Comment: @Nul You always have the ability to delete your questions and answers (and by extension, undelete it). It's true that you're not allowed to see the deleted question when the page is refreshed, but you're allowed to see your own deleted answers if you know the link to the question. So the ability to undelete is useful when you delete an answer and then improve it and undelete. It's probably easier to code and maintain undelete rights across both questions and answers the same way. The system only makes a check to see if the post can be deleted (i.e., is not accepted or has no upvoted answers)

Comment: @yoda Yeah, I figured that would be the case. I still think anyone [should be able to see their deleted questions.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108077/dont-remove-deleted-questions-from-owners-view-and-let-them-see-them-regardles)

Comment: Probably worth noting that if a *moderator* deletes your post, you can't undelete it. No matter how much rep you have. Ditto for spam/offensive-deleted posts.